# KeyDecodingStrategy .convertFromSnakeCase doesn't work

Tags: ios, json, swift, rx-swift, decodable

I've got an adapter class called ServiceHealthApi that has this function:

```
final class ServiceHealthApi {
    let mockApi = "https://staging.myapp.com/health"

    func getHealth() -> Single<ServiceHealthResponseModel> {
        let url = URL(string: mockApi)
        guard let validUrl = url else { return .never() }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: validUrl)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        let headers = [
            "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ]
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: urlRequest)
            .take(1)
            .map {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                return try JSONDecoder().decode(ServiceHealthResponseModel.self, from: $0) }
            .asSingle()

    }
}

struct HealthResponseModel: Decodable {
    struct DataResponse: Decodable {
        let serviceName: String
        let serviceStatus: String
        let serviceOperational: Bool
    }

    struct Meta: Decodable {
        let statusCode: Int
        let statusMessage: String
    }

    let data: [DataResponse]
    let meta: Meta
}
```

The `JSON` string that is supposed to be parsed is like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "service_operational": true
        },
        {
            "service_name": "orm",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "service_operational": true
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "status_code": 200,
        "status_message": "OK"
    }
}
```

Now, when I tried to run my integration test, it failed with this error from the `JSONDecoder`:

> error keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "serviceName", intValue:
>   nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue:
>   0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: \"serviceName\", intValue: nil)
>   (\"serviceName\").", underlyingError: nil))

The funny thing is, if I disabled .convertFromSnakeCase, and just use camelcase for the variable names in the response model, it worked just fine. I know I can probably use coding keys, but I am just wondering, why didn't my implementation work?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've tried parsing the `JSON` string directly without calling the `API` and it did work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a second `JSONDecoder` without any strategy

Replace

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
return try JSONDecoder().decode(ServiceHealthResponseModel.self, from: $0) }
```

with

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
return try decoder.decode(ServiceHealthResponseModel.self, from: $0) }
```

Comment: Oh damn, You're right. I'm embarrassed that I didn't notice it earlier. This error is such an elementary one. To think that I've spend almost an hour trying to figure it out. Now I feel so silly. Anyway, thank you very much.